# SFML texture usage issue

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to make a tilemap but when I run this code, the tiles becomes white, the texture has a problem. I know it that from the sf::Texture reference [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem) says that the texture must exist in order to that the sprite can use it. But I dont know how to make it possible.
Here's the code:

```
class Tile
{
private:
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Texture tex;

public:
     Tile(int x, int y, sf::Texture tex)
    {
this->tex = tex;
this->sprite.setTexture(this->tex);
this->sprite.setPosition(x, y);

    }
    void render(sf::RenderWindow* target)
    {
    target->draw(this->sprite);
    }


class Tilemap
{
private:
Tile tiles[36][64];
sf::Texture tex[4];

public:
//const/dest
Tilemap()
{
this->tex[0].loadFromFile("Resources/Tilemap/Water/water1.png");

int x = -WIDTH+WIDTH/2;
int y = -HEIGTH/2;
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
        this->tiles[i][j] = Tile(x, y, this->tex[0]);
        x += 60;
    }
    y += 60;
    x = -WIDTH + WIDTH / 2;
}

}


render(sf::RenderWindow* target, sf::Vector2f pos)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
        this->tiles[i][j].render(target);
    }
}
 };
 Tilemap map;
 map = Tilemap();
```

Thank you in advance for any answers :)

Comment: Are you certain that the program can find the texture at `"Resources/Tilemap/Water/water1.png"`? Try giving it a full system path (e.g. `"C:/user/Resources/Tilemap/Water/water1.png"` and see what happens.

Comment: You can also check the return-value of `loadFromFile`. It returns false if the image fails to load.

Comment: I have already did it and there's no problem with the loading.

Comment: You never seem to initialize `sf::Texture tex[4];`.

Comment: I thought that when I use only the tex[0] I have to initialize only the one.

Comment: Please some answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved it by myself. Every tile has one `sf::Texture tex` and every time I need to change it I just load it again from different file.